# SVN - Tuleap Integration with LDAP

Tags: svn, authentication, ldap, tuleap

I am browsing Subversion tree in Tuleap 7.6.99.23

I get the following error :

> OPERATIONS_ERROR: {'info': '00002020: Operation unavailable without authentication', 'desc': 'Operations error'}

with a new user created in my AD ( samba 4 ) .

I can login to TULEAP with my LDAP id and pass with no problem.

> PS : Yes I use $sys_ldap_server = "ldap://x.x.x.x to connect to my LDAP in ldap.inc

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to configure the authentication in ldap.inc

```
$sys_ldap_bind_dn = "eduid=1234,ou=people,dc=tuleap,dc=com";
$sys_ldap_bind_passwd = "xxxxxxxxx";
```